# Entity Framework map multiple columns to C# complex type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table where I use four columns as the primary key: Major, Minor, MajorRevision, MinorRevision.

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1 Code-First lazy loading, can someone give me an example of how I can map those columns to a c# System.Version type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example:

```
    public class TableV {
        public int Major { get; set; }
        public int Minor { get; set; }
        public int MajorRevision { get; set; }
        public int MinorRevision { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        System.Version Version {
            get { return new Version(Major, Minor, MajorRevision, MinorRevision}
            set {Major = value.Major; Minor = value.Minor; MajorRevision = value.MajorRevision; MinorRevision = value.MinorRevision; }
        }
    }
```

but you can't use Version in queries.