# Storing System.Version in database with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first, entity-framework-migrations, complextype

I have a database that is created using Entity Framework 6.1 Code First, I have one specific table I am having issues with.

I have a table called Manifests, the entity definition is below

```
public class Manifest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public int VersionMajor { get; set; }
    public int VersionMinor { get; set; }
    public int VersionBuild { get; set; }
    public int VersionRevision { get; set; }
    public Version Version
    {
        get
        {
            return new Version(this.VersionMajor, this.VersionMinor, this.VersionBuild, this.VersionRevision);
        }

        set
        {
            this.VersionMajor = value.Major;
            this.VersionMinor = value.Minor;
            this.VersionBuild = value.Build;
            this.VersionRevision = value.Revision;
        }
    }
    public string ReleaseNotes { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompulsory { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string UpdatePackage { get; set; }
}
```

You will notice that I have a property defined which is a `System.Version` and will store the manifest version, however, when I run add-migration in the package manager console the resulting migration does not include the `Version` column.  I have tried setting the `modelBuilder.ComplexType<System.Version>()` in `OnModelCreating` but to no avail, please help?

As suggested I have changed the entity definition (see above), but I am now getting an error when running the seed, please see below:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException: 
(6,10) : error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 6:No mapping specified for properties Manifest.Version in Set Manifests.
An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
  Entity is type [Drogo.Meera.Data.Context.Manifest]
```

The seed method has the following:

```
context.Manifests.AddOrUpdate(
    p => p.Version,
    new Manifest
        {
            Description = "Initial Release",
            VersionMajor = 1,
            VersionMinor = 0,
            VersionBuild = 0,
            IsCompulsory = true,
            ReleaseDate = DateTime.Now,
            ReleaseNotes = "Initial Release",
            UpdatePackage = @"v1-0-0\v1-0-0.zip"
        });
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: It shouldn't create a `Version` column, it should create multiple columns with names like `Version_Major` and `Version_Minor`.

Comment: Ok, it's definitely not doing that, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the error, it looks like you'll have to explicitly ignore `Manifest.Version` -- I didn't think you would need to. Use `modelBuilder.Entity<Manifest>().Ignore(m => m.Version);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're not seeing what you're expecting when you're using `System.Version` as a complex type since it doesn't have any valid properties for EF to use.

> If a property has only a getter or a setter, but not both, it will not be included in the model.

*https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch05s07.html*

---

You should be able to work around this by pulling out the properties you want to keep yourself (and marking `Manifest.Version` as a property to ignore).

```
public class Manifest
{
    // other properties

    int VersionMajor { get; set; }
    int VersionMinor { get; set; }
    int VersionBuild { get; set; }
    int VersionRevision { get; set; }

    public Version Version 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return new Version(VersionMajor, VersionMinor, VersionBuild, VersionRevision); 
        }
        set
        {
            VersionMajor = value.Major;
            VersionMinor = value.Minor;
            VersionBuild = value.Build;
            VersionRevision = value.Revision;
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Adding [NotMapped] to Manifest.Version would also work, as in the link below
modelBuilder.Entity<Manifest>().Ignore(m => m.Version);
```

There's another example here: [Entity Framework map multiple columns to C# complex type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308499/entity-framework-map-multiple-columns-to-c-sharp-complex-type)